# Trying to remember a movie about North African freedom fighters battling a European power

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched it as a young kid so it had to be an early or mid 80's movie. World War I era. North Africans fighting for freedom from a European power. An older man leads the North Africans and I think he dies in the end.

The one scene I really remember is the European power is sending an armed force across a iron/steel bridge and the freedom fighters are camped out above in caves. They attack the forces on the bridge. I can not remember if they blow up the bridge or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the movie you want is [Lion of the Desert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_of_the_Desert), which is about Libyan freedom fighter [Omar Mukhtar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_Mukhtar)'s fight against the Italian army which was occupying Libya at the time.

[image: Lion of the Desert]